# Restore specific transaction logs from backup

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

What I did:
1. I restored last full backup of the database and last differential backup created after full.

I want to restore transaction log from the .bak file, but only last 2 logs, because, the previous made before differential backup. I can't check only this because of mssql check automatically all. How to change it?
[image]

Comment: Is the database currently recovery pending? You could use T-SQL `RESTORE LOG` rather than the SSMS UI.

Comment: @DanGuzman yes, it's current recovery pending.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the latest SSMS version 17.2. Not sure if I'm doing something different. I think T-SQL would be the best option. You can script that from SSMS and just run the last 2 `RESTORE LOG` statements plus the 'WITH RECOVERY'.